# C# Linq to sum and group XML

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Hi guys I need some direction with how to layout a group and sum of a variable from within an XML file on C#.
The XML document is as follows:

```
    <xxxx>
       <yy>
            <pp a= "b">
            <aa> 3 </aa>
       </yy>
       <yy>
            <pp a= "c">
            <aa> 5 </aa>
       </yy>
         <yy>
            <pp a= "b">
            <aa> 6 </aa>
       </yy>
    </xxxx>
```

How would I go about creating a C# Linq query to group attributes(a) and sum the (aa) element totals?

Comment: Have a look at [linq to xml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/mt693062.aspx) for processing the xml elements.

Comment: Your XML wasn't valid unless I put in a `</pp>` after the `<pp `.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from d in xmldoc.Descendants("yy")
group d by d.Element("pp").Attribute("a").Value into dg
select new { a = dg.Key, sum = dg.Sum(d => Int64.Parse(d.Element("aa").Value)) }
```